# Magento2 JS files not loaded

Tags: magento2, theme, development

Having problems with js Files on my local install backend/frontend. I get 404 on all referenced JS files. I already cleaned couple of times the cache and deleted `pub/static` but the same problem occurs. I have developer mod enabled.

If I try to access directly require.js I get

```
File '/...../' does not exists.
vendor/magento/module-media-storage/Model/File/Storage/Response.php(59): Magento\Framework\File\Transfer\Adapter\Http->send
```

Comment: Do you modify anything in core? Try to re-deploy all static-files by `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` Make sure you clear right files. Must have file static.php in folder `pub` and file .htaccess in `pub\static`

Comment: I got it between  pub\static needs to have proper rights